# Do the blades from the eldian forces have anything special to be able to cut giant limbs?

Tags: attack-on-titan

The eldian forces are merely human size, when Kyojins are from 2 to 15 meters in average, however with blades they are capable to cut meters long of giant limbs in a single swing.

Do the blades from the eldian forces have anything special to be able to cut giant limbs?